# Jquery Same Origin Ajax Call Mistake

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, .htaccess, joomla

The site in question is test1.guru99.com
I am making SAME ORIGIN like this

```
var myemail = "test@gmail.com";

       jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'GET', //Define the method type
            url:'http://test1.guru99.com/Customization/popup/subscription-list.php',
            data: {email: myemail},
            success: function(d) {
                console.log('success');
            },
        });
```

But I get error like

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CORS error happens because your site is not "**test1.guru99.com**". It is "**www.test1.guru99.com**". (*it gets automatically redirected*)

So since you want the script to run from the same domain, just exclude the domain from it

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET', //Define the method type
        url:'/Customization/popup/subscription-list.php',
        data: {email: myemail},
        success: function(d) {
            console.log('success');
        }
    });
```

(*but it will not solve the 500 error*)

Comment: Thanks I was able to resolve COR issue. But I still get 500 Error. Is it due to the version of Jquery I am using or htaccess?http://screencast.com/t/3xGGiJIw

Comment: The 500 error has nothing to do with jQuery. It is a problem of the ***subscription-list.php*** file. You get when visiting the http://test1.guru99.com/Customization/popup/subscription-list.php directly

Comment: Yes the issue was with file permissions. Error Fixed now

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this error because the domains of the requesting/receiving sites are different.

The site you're requesting *from* is `www.test1.guru99.com`, the receiver is `test1.guru99.com`. Note that every part of the domain *must* match, down to the subdomain and protocol.

Assuming the `www.` subdomain points to the same place, I would suggest you amend your `$.ajax` call to use a relative path.

Comment: Thanks I was able to resolve COR issue. But I still get 500 Error. Is it due to the version of Jquery I am using or htaccess?http://screencast.com/t/3xGGiJIw

Comment: A 500 error means that there was an issue with your server-side code. You need to debug your PHP.